# "Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x103c93c50) to 'NSNumber' (0x103535b88)" Error

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I created an `SQLite` table with a row `id integer PRIMARY KEY`. I used [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/) to integrate `SQLite` with my app. I'm trying to add that to an `array` of `Ints`. Here's my code:

```swift
let all = "select id from \(self.tableName)"
let fullArray = self.dbManager.loadDataFromDB(all)

for currentObject in fullArray {  
    println(currentObject[0])
    println(_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(currentObject[0]))
    self.tableViewData.append(currentObject[0] as! Int) //tableViewData is an array of Ints
}
```

Results of `println` statements:

> 2 
>   
> Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional

When I run the app, I get the following error at the last line of the code.

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x103c93c50) to
>   'NSNumber' (0x103535b88).

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the following lines in your tutorial code:

```c
// Convert the column data to text (characters).
char *dbDataAsChars = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, i);
```

All the results are converted to strings, that means the DB type `integer` is not kept in results and you have to use something like:

```c
for currentObject in fullArray as! [String] {  
    // Int(currentObject[0])! in Swift 2
    self.tableViewData.append(currentObject[0].toInt()) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
self.tableViewData.append(currentObject[0].toInt())
```

Comment: I get an error saying "`'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'toInt()'`" I think that's Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the data in the array are all Ints? I had a similar problem using the Flickr API, since print() statement showed that it was returning Int values.

However it was actually returning String values. Try casting as a String first, then use Int() to convert to integer if required.